# Как получить значение переменной с функции другого файла .py

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, переменные

main.py

```
await relocation_fun(state, user_id=message.from_user.id)
# Как мне result получить тут?
```

DB.py

```
async def relocation_fun(state, user_id):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        result = cur.execute("SELECT `User_id` FROM `users` WHERE `FIO` = ? ", (data['who'],)).fetchone()
        return result   
# Этот результат получить в main.py
```

Comment: Тебе известно, для чего там написано слово return?

Comment: Return возвращает значение полученное в функции и его можно присвоить переменной, но мне нужно переменной в другом файле

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете присвоить результат вызова этой функции переменной в файле main.py. Результат вызова функции присваивается переменной result, которую можно использовать дальше в коде

## main.py

```
from DB import relocation_fun

result = await relocation_fun(state, user_id=message.from_user.id)
```

Comment: спасибо , получилось